# how can I lower the CPU and I/O priority of a cron script?

Tags: php, unix, cron

I want to run a script via cron at low I/O and CPU priority. If I understand correctly (and I might not), I could just add `proc_nice(10);` to my script to lower the CPU priority, but there is no PHP equivalent for I/O priority.

There appears to be a shell command `ionice` for this, but I am a linux idiot, and I don't know what I am doing. Would this be the correct line for my cron file if I want to use both nice and ionice to lower the priority of the script in question?

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/nice -n 10 /usr/bin/ionice -c 3 /path/php/bin/php /path/script.php
```

I got the `-c3` parameter from [here](http://friedcpu.wordpress.com/2007/07/17/why-arent-you-using-ionice-yet/) ("places the process in the idle scheduling class"), and I'm not confident that's what I want.

Is there a benefit to using the PHP call to `proc_nice()` rather than this method?

EDIT: my cron script is not running using the above, so I've definitely misunderstood something

Comment: [`# man ionice`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice)

Comment: try system("renice -5 -p ".getmypid());

Comment: Maybe ask at unix.stackexchange.com , this is not related with programming. I tried to report it as offtopic, but I cant choose unix in moderation form (not sure why).

Comment: "Would this be the correct line for my cron file if I want to use both nice and ionice to lower the priority of the script in question?"

It appears to be - but what error are you seeing that makes it think it's not?

Answer (score 0):

Unix and its clones tend to have the concept of the output of one utility program/command becoming the input of the next.

In your example the result is (I think) that the `nice` will actually affect the niceness of the `ionice`.  Only the `ionice` would have an affect on PHP.

(**UPDATE**: Actually, it should inherit its niceness, see comment)

I found [a page](http://docs.moodle.org/20/en/Cron_with_UNIX) that suggests doing the following to have both `nice` and `ionice` affect your PHP instance:

```
ionice -c3 -p$$;nice -n 10 /usr/bin/php /path/to/your/script.php
```

Comment: Wont give you a -1, but niceness (ie. scheduling priority) is generally inherited, so setting the niceness of `ionice` should work correctly. Also note that unless you are the superuser (or have the `CAP_SYS_NICE` capability), you can only ever decrease your priority.

Comment: Edited answer for that, thanks for pointing that out.  But would the suggested fix from the page I linked to work?

Comment: AFAICT, it will work, since it sets the shell's IO priority which I think is also inherited. If it does, it would be equivalent to the original line.